# redirection for deleted pages

Tags: wordpress

Hi I need to find a way to redirect deleted pages to another pages using 301 redirection, to a specific page depending on the URL of the page.If the url is 
http://example.com/projects/test-page-redirectpage/ then it should be redirect to the 'redirectpage' after page deletion.There are hundreds of pages like that which have 'redirectpage' at the end of URL,so I can not do that manually by and redirection plugin.I have wrote following code but it is only working by page name.I want such a function which can detect that the 'redirectpage' from the URL and if that url is not exit then it should be redirect to the 'redirectpage'

```
function get_page_by_name($pagename)
{
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ($pages as $page) if ($page->post_name == $pagename) return $page;
return false;
}
function redirect_301() {
$page = get_page_by_name('test-page-redirectpage');
if (empty($page)) {
wp_safe_redirect( home_url('http://example.com/redirectpage/'), 301 );
exit;
} 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_301', 1 );
```

Comment: Note that a 310 redirection is not the proper measure for deleted pages. The [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.11) defines a "410 GONE" message for content that is no longer available. There is a [WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-410/) that does that job for deleted content. It also allows you to create a template file for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with using `template_redirect` but you should be checking if the URL can be translated to post ID and the current request URL (from global `$wp` object) for occurrence of `redirectpage` string (at the end of it):

```
function so_423_redirectpage_redirect()
{
    global $wp;

    if (url_to_postid(home_url($wp->request)) === 0 &&
    ('redirectpage' === substr(untrailingslashit($wp->request), -12) || 'redirect-page' === substr(untrailingslashit($wp->request), -13))) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('http://example.com/redirectpage/'), 301);
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'so_423_redirectpage_redirect');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to redirect all the pages which have 'redirectpage' string at the end,I want to redirect only those url which have deleted or not exist.

Comment: Suppose this url is not exist  http://example.com/projects/hello-redirectpage/ and if user goes to that page then user should be redirect to the
http://example.com/redirectpage/

Comment: @Johny, I've edited the code and it's using `url_to_postid` to check if page exists

Comment: Thanks its working,but if my last slug is 'redirect-page' beside 'redirectpage' then what should be the format?

Comment: What code should be when url will be http://example.com/projects/hello-redirect-page beside http://example.com/projects/hello-redirectpage

Comment: @Johny, I've edited the answer to allow "redirect-page" string

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the 404.php file template here (from your theme), so you're pretty sure that the page visited doesn't exist. 
Before the get_header() function you can do the following check:

```
$requested_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
if(strpos(array_pop($requested_uri), '-redirectpage') !== FALSE) {
    wp_safe_redirect(site_url('redirectpage'), 301);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using 404. Perhaps it can be combined with my answer and instead of checking with `url_to_postid()` to use `is_404()`